# i want to get all the records of the names that begin with a particular letter, using mvc 4 asp web api

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

```
[Route("api/Student/{name}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string name)
{
    using (studentContext sc = new studentContext())
    {
        var entity = sc.Students.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(name)) ;

        if (entity != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, entity);
        }

        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Staff with name:" + name.ToString() + "not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What excactly is not working? Do you receive errors?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ToList()` to fetch the data from the database.

```
 var entity = sc.Students.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[Route("api/Student/{name}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string name)
{
    using (studentContext sc = new studentContext())
    {
        var students = sc.Students.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(name)).ToList();

        if (students != null && students.Count() > 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, students);
        }    
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Staff with name:" + name.ToString() + "not found");
        }
    }
}
```